# Haxe: Native Interface properties implementable?

Tags: haxe

I've got this compiletime errors when I make some class implement an interface with properties that have been fromerly defined in some native sub class, like openfl.display.Sprite. It occurs when I'm targeting flash, not js.

```
Field get_someValue needed by SomeInterface is missing
Field set_someValue needed by SomeInterface is missing
Field someValue has different property access than in SomeInterface (var should be (get,set))
```

In contrast, there's no problem with interface definitions of 'native' methods or 'non-native' properties. Those work.

Do I have to avoid that (not so typical) use of interfaces with haxe and rewrite my code? Or is there any way to bypass this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
class NativePropertyInterfaceImplTest 
{
    public function new() 
    {
        var spr:FooSprite = new FooSprite();
        spr.visible = !spr.visible;
    }
}

class FooSprite extends Sprite implements IFoo
{
    public function new()
    {
        super();
    }
}

interface IFoo 
{
    public var visible (get, set):Bool; // Cannot use this ):
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You need to use a slightly different signature on the Flash target:

```js
interface IFoo 
{
    #if flash
    public var visible:Bool;
    #else
    public var visible (get, set):Bool;
    #end
}
```

#### Additional Information

Haxe `get` and `set` imply that `get_property():T` and `set_property(value:T):T` both exist. OpenFL uses this syntax for many properties, including `displayObject.visible`.

Core ActionScript VM classes (such as `Sprite`) don't use Haxe `get`/`set`, but are native properties. This is why they look different.

#### Overriding Core Properties

If you ever need to override core properties like this, here is an example of how you would do so for both Flash and other targets on OpenFL:

```js
class CustomSprite extends Sprite {

    private var _visible:Bool = true;

    public function new () {

        super ();

    }

    #if flash

    @:getter(visible) private function get_visible ():Bool { return _visible; }
    @:setter(visible) private function set_visible (value:Bool):Void { _visible = value; }

    #else

    private override function get_visible ():Bool { return _visible; }
    private override function set_visible (value:Bool):Bool { return _visible = value; }

    #end

}
```

#### Overriding Custom Properties

This is not needed for custom properties, which are the same on all platforms:

```js
class BaseClass {

    public var name (default, set):String;

    public function new () {

    }

    private function set_name (value:String) {

        return this.name = value;

    }

}

class SuperClass {

    public function new () {

        super ();

    }

    private override function set_name (value:String):String {

        return this.name = value + " Q. Public";

    }

}
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that there is another specific case here:
    var parent (default, null) :DisplayObjectContainer;

In this case no conditional compiling seems to be needed. I guess, it is because 'default' is used instead of 'get', so because it is 'physical'.

Answer (score 0):

Need to provide the method signatures in an Interface. Currently its just a property declaration.

The error message is saying it all.

`Field get_someValue needed by SomeInterface is missing
Field set_someValue needed by SomeInterface is missing`

Hopefully that helps.